# Building a slide down search box in wordpress

Tags: javascript, search, wp-enqueue-script, html

I am building a slide down search box.  I have successfully coded it, and it does work on jsfiddle.  However, when I am trying to implement it on wordpress it does not work.  Since it does work on jsfiddle it has to be something on wordpress, but I don't see what the problem is. Does anyone see any errors?

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jd0a433f/1/

searchform.php

```html
<div class="search-field">
</div>
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
  <label for="search-input" id="search-label" class="search-label">
    Search for:   
    </label>
<input id="search-input" type="search" class="search-input" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" />
  <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

search.js

```html
document.getElementById("search-label").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target == this) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.classList.toggle("clicked");
  }
});
```

functions.php

```html
function searchfunction() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/search.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'searchfunction' );
```

css

```html
#ht-masthead .search-field {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url(images/search-icon.png);
  background-position: 5px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 37px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 34px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
  transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
  width: 230px;
}

#ht-masthead .search-field:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #c3c0ab;
  cursor: text;
  outline: 0;
}
#ht-masthead .search-form {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  top: 200px;
}
.search-toggle:hover #ht-masthead .search-form {
  display: block;
}
.search-form
    .search-submit {
  display: none;
}

.search-form {
  position: relative;
}

.search-form label {
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-search-strong-128.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  text-indent: 9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.search-input {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transition: opacity .25s, transform .25s;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;

}
.search-label, .search-input {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: .5em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.clicked + .search-input {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

footer.php*

```html
<footer class="site-footer">
    <!-- footer-widgets -->
    <div class="footer-line"></div>
<div class="footer-widgets clearfix">
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer1')) : ?>
<div class="footer-widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer1'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer2')) : ?>
<div class="footer-widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer2'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer3')) : ?>
<div class="footer-widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer3'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer4')) : ?>
<div class="footer-widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('footer4'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- /footer-widgets -->
         <nav class="site-nav">
                <?php 

             $args = array(
                'theme_location' => 'footer'
             );

              ?>

             <?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>

            </nav>

<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;"><p id="copyright">&copy; <?php echo date('Y');?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | </div>
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;"><?wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'new-menu', 'container_class' => 'secondary-footer' ) ); ?></p></div>

</footer>

</footer>

</div><!-- container -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be the way you are implimenting it.
It appears that you are trying to add this to your theme as individual files however I do not see anywhere in the code you provided where you are calling on the searchform.php file in the theme itself.

As such I tested the code you provided and was able to successfully get it to work on my custom theme by adjusting the location of where I placed the code snippets you provided.

Here was my steps.

First I placed searchform.php code into the header.php file of my theme.

```
 <div class="search-field">
 </div>
 <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
   <label for="search-input" id="search-label" class="search-label">
     Search for:   
     </label>
 <input id="search-input" type="search" class="search-input" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" />
   <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
 </form>
```

Next I placed search.js into the footer.php file of my theme by adding the script tag around it and adding it right before the closing  tag.

```
 <script>
 document.getElementById("search-label").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   if (e.target == this) {
     e.preventDefault();
     this.classList.toggle("clicked");
   }
 });
 </script>
```

After that I added your function to functions.php of the custom theme

```
 function searchfunction() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/search.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'searchfunction' );
```

Finally I added your css style to themes stylesheet.

```
 #ht-masthead .search-field {
 background-color: transparent;
 background-image: url(images/search-icon.png);
 background-position: 5px center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 24px 24px;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 37px;
 margin: 3px 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 34px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
 transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
 width: 230px;
 }

 #ht-masthead .search-field:focus {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 2px solid #c3c0ab;
 cursor: text;
 outline: 0;
 }
 #ht-masthead .search-form {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 right: 200px;
 top: 200px;
 }
 .search-toggle:hover #ht-masthead .search-form {
 display: block;
 }
 .search-form
 .search-submit {
 display: none;
 }

 .search-form {
 position: relative;
 }

 .search-form label {
 position: relative;
 background: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-search-strong-128.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 50px; height: 50px;
 text-indent: 9999px;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 }

 .search-input {
 transform: translateY(-100%);
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 transition: opacity .25s, transform .25s;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;

 }
 .search-label, .search-input {
 background: #ccc;
 padding: .5em;
 display: inline-block;
 }

 .clicked + .search-input {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: translateY(0);
 }
```

When I load the page I can see the same functionality as on your jsfiddle example you provided. I did notice with my theme, due to me having the header utilizing a high number z-index that it was hiding behind my header when it initially opened. However it is loading up on the site correctly.

Try this solution out and I hope it suits your needs.

Comment: How did you add the javascript into the footer.php?  I added my footer.php into my original question.  Would you mind showing me how to place the javascript in?

Comment: Simply add the <script></script> tags around your script and add it right before the closing body tag. (typically located in the footer.php file for your theme.) I have updated the answer to reflect these changes.